# updates.micrsoft.com blocked on laptop

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update, spyware

I'm trying to repair a family member's laptop.

It had some spyware on it called "whitesmoke" that I've removed. Everything seems to be working fine and a full scan with Microsoft Security Essentials comes up clean.

However if I try to go to http://update.microsoft.com it won't load.

I've tried Internet Explorer 8 and Chrome; in Chrome I get the following error:

> Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown error

I've looked at the hosts file and have removed all entries but I can't think of anywhere else where this site might be blocked from.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use a system which had spyware or a virus on it. Simply backup any data and do a fresh install. The spyware may have loaded other viruses like rootkits or trojans. Especially do a clean install if you are using the computer for online shopping or online banking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your proxy server settings.

1. "Control Panel" (from the Start Menu)
2. "Internet Options" icon
3. "Connections" tab
4. "LAN Settings" button
5. "Proxy server" section
6. Turn off the checkbox to disable the proxy server

Some SpyWare and viruses change the proxy server setting to themselves.  Once removed, if the proxy server setting hasn't been removed then you can end up with problems such as this.

Comment: Also, you should download and install and run MalwareBytes to remove any left-over SpyWare on your system:  http://www.malwarebytes.org/

Comment: This, it's probably this.